# Will updating ios app remove the websql database?

Tags: ios, database, cordova

For an app called A:
I know installation after one uninstalls A will remove the websql database.

How about update?
In general:
Install A-->Uninstall A-->Install A again. (This steps will remove the websql database).

How about the following steps,
Install A-->Update A(Install A) without uninstalling.

Will that remove the local database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you place / create the database files in Documents folder, updating an iOS App via App Store will not remove files within the App, unless you did it explicitly.